# Is there a reason to believe that this process is not random?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Below is a problem I did. Is my solution right?

Problem:
A jury of $6$ persons was selected from a group of $20$ potential jurios,
of whom $8$ we black and $12$ were white. The jury was supposedly
randomly selected but it contained only one black member. Do you have any
reason to doubt the randomness of the selection?
Answer:
Let $p_0$ be the probability that we have no black people on the jury. Let $p_1$ be the probability that we have one black person on the jury. Let $p_2$ be the probability that we have three black people on the jury.
$$ p_0 = \dfrac{ {12 \choose 6} }{{20 \choose 6} } $$
$$ {12 \choose 6} = \dfrac{ 12(11)(10)(9)(8)(7) } { 6(5)(4)(3)(2)} $$
$$ {12 \choose 6} = \dfrac{ 11(10)(9)(8)(7) } { 5(4)(3)} $$
$$ {12 \choose 6} = \dfrac{ 11(9)(8)(7) } { 2(3)} $$
$$ {12 \choose 6} = 11(3)(4)(7) = 924 $$
$$ {20 \choose 6} = \dfrac{ 20(19)(18)(17)(16)(15)}{ 6(5)(4)(3)(2) } $$
$$ {20 \choose 6} = \dfrac{ 19(18)(17)(16)(15)}{ 6(3)(2) } $$
$$ {20 \choose 6} = 19(17)(8)(15) $$
$$ p_0 = \dfrac{ 924 }{ 19(17)(8)(15) } $$
$$ p_0 = \dfrac{ 231 }{ 19(17)(2)(15) }
    = \dfrac{ 77 }{ 19(17)(2)(5) } $$
$$ p_0 =  \dfrac{ 77 } { 3230 } $$
$$ p_0 \doteq 0.0238390 $$
$$ p_1 = \dfrac{ {12 \choose 5}{6 \choose 1}  }{{20 \choose 6} } $$
$$ {12 \choose 5} = \dfrac{ 12(11)(10)(9)(8) }{5(4)(3)(2)} $$
$$ {12 \choose 5} = \dfrac{ 11(10)(9)(8) }{5(2)} = 11(9)(8) $$
$$ {6 \choose 1} = 6 $$
$$ p_1 =  \dfrac{ 11(9)(8)(6) } { 19(17)(8)(15)  } $$
$$ p_1 =  \dfrac{ 11(9)(6) } { 19(17)(15)  } $$
$$ p_1 =  \dfrac{ 11(3)(6)} { 19(17)(5)  } $$
$$ p_1 =  \dfrac{ 198 } { 1615 } $$
$$ p_1 \doteq 0.1226006 $$
$$ p_2 = \dfrac{ {12 \choose 4}{6 \choose 2}  }{{20 \choose 6} } $$
$$ {12 \choose 4} = \dfrac{ 12(11)(10)(9) }{4(3)(2)} $$
$$ {12 \choose 4} = \dfrac{ 11(10)(9)  }{2 } = 11(5)(9) $$
$$ {6 \choose 2} = \dfrac{ 6(5) }{2} = 15 $$
$$ p_2 = \dfrac{ 11(5)(9)(15) }{19(17)(8)(15)} $$
$$ p_2 = \dfrac{ 495 } { 2584 } $$
$$ p_2 \doteq 0.1915635 $$
Yes, there is a good reason to question if the selection was random.

Here is my revise answer. Is it right now?

Let $p_0$ be the probability that we have no black people on the jury. Let $p_1$ be the probability that we have one black person on the jury. Let $p_2$ be the probability that we have two black people on the jury.
\begin{align*}
p_0 &= \dfrac{ {12 \choose 6} }{{20 \choose 6} } \\
{12 \choose 6} &= \dfrac{ 12(11)(10)(9)(8)(7) } { 6(5)(4)(3)(2)} \\
{12 \choose 6} &= \dfrac{ 11(10)(9)(8)(7) } { 5(4)(3)} \\
{12 \choose 6} &= \dfrac{ 11(9)(8)(7) } { 2(3)} \\
{12 \choose 6} &= 11(3)(4)(7) = 924 \\
{20 \choose 6} &= \dfrac{ 20(19)(18)(17)(16)(15)}{ 6(5)(4)(3)(2) } \\
{20 \choose 6} &= \dfrac{ 19(18)(17)(16)(15)}{ 6(3)(2) } \\
{20 \choose 6} &= 19(17)(8)(15) \\
p_0 &= \dfrac{ 924 }{ 19(17)(8)(15) } \\
p_0 &= \dfrac{ 231 }{ 19(17)(2)(15) }
    = \dfrac{ 77 }{ 19(17)(2)(5) }\\
p_0 &=  \dfrac{ 77 } { 3230 } \\
p_0 &\doteq 0.0238390
\end{align*}
\begin{align*} 
p_1 &= \dfrac{ {12 \choose 5}{8 \choose 1}  }{{20 \choose 6} } \\
{12 \choose 5} &= \dfrac{ 12(11)(10)(9)(8) }{5(4)(3)(2)} \\
{12 \choose 5} &= \dfrac{ 11(10)(9)(8) }{5(2)} = 11(9)(8) \\
{8 \choose 1} &= 8 \\
p_1 &=  \dfrac{ 11(9)(8)(8) } { 19(17)(8)(15)  } \\
p_1 &=  \dfrac{ 11(9)(8) } { 19(17)(15)  } \\
p_1 &=  \dfrac{ 11(3)(8) } { 19(17)(5)  } \\
p_1 &= \dfrac{ 264 }{ 1615 } \\
p_1 &\doteq 0.1634675
\end{align*}
\begin{align*} 
p_2 &= \dfrac{ {12 \choose 4}{8 \choose 2}  }{{20 \choose 6} } \\
{12 \choose 4} &= \dfrac{ 12(11)(10)(9) }{4(3)(2)} \\
{12 \choose 4} &= \dfrac{ 11(10)(9)  }{2 } = 11(5)(9) \\
{8 \choose 2} &= \dfrac{ 8(7) }{2} = 28 \\
p_2 &= \dfrac{ 11(5)(9)(28) }{19(17)(8)(15)} \\
p_2 &= \dfrac{ 11(9)(28) }{19(17)(8)(3} \\
p_2 &= \dfrac{ 11(9)(7) }{19(17)(2)(3} \\
p_2 &= \dfrac{ 693 } { 1938 } \\
p_2 &= \dfrac{ 231 } { 646 } \\
p_2 &\doteq 0.3575851
\end{align*}
I would now tend to believe the process was random.

Comment: I didn't check the computations but assuming they were right, why do you conclude that there is a good reason to question if the selection is random? 12% is not a particularly unfeasible probability of an event occurring.

Comment: I view 12% as unlikely and therefore it seems to me that the process may not have been random. I am hoping you or somebody will check my computations.

Comment: The computations for $p_1$ and $p_2$ are not correct. The computation for $p_0$ is correct. You can also easily verify this type of thing yourself using a calculator

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%2812+choose+5%29%288+choose+1%29%2F%2820+choose+6%29

Comment: Looks like you were doing $6 \choose x$ instead of $8 \choose x$